# Search in Mapped JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I need to implement search within this JSON, I've tried to do it but it's giving me error. Below is my code and Modal Class which I've mapped.

After trying every possible way, I still cannot resolve this error.

My code for search:

```
 self.company = self.companyDetails.filter{ _ in self.companyDetails.company_name.range(of: searchKey) }
```

Showing error:

> Value of type '[companiesDetail]' has no member 'company_name'

```
Alamofire.request("http://34.210.142.70/isdental/api/v2.0/home/companies", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: params).responseObject  { (response:DataResponse<ContactRealm>) in            
   let ContactsRes = response.result.value        
   self.companyDetails = ContactsRes?.companies as! [companiesDetail]           
   self.company = ContactsRes?.companies  as! [companiesDetail]        
}
```

Below is My JSON :

```
{
"error": false,
"message": "Companies fetched succesfully",
"companies": [
    {
        "company_id": 1,
        "company_name": "3M Espe India",
        "company_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/v2.0/companies/3m_espe.png",
        "company_website": "http://solutions.3mindia.co.in/wps/portal/3M/en_IN/3M-ESPE-APAC/",
        "company_email": "",
        "company_description": "",
        "company_categories": "General Equipment / Preventives & Oral Care / General & Restorative",
        "company_contacts": [
            {
                "contact_id": 1,
                "contact_name": "Zonal Office",
                "contact_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/v2.0/contacts/company_office.png",
                "contact_phone": "+91 8022231414",
                "contact_location": "Bangalore",
                "contact_favourite": false,
                "contact_email": "3mespe.in@mmm.com",
                "contact_website": "",
                "contact_type": 1
            },
            {
                "contact_id": 367,
                "contact_name": "3A Dental Company",
                "contact_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/v2.0/contacts/dealer.png",
                "contact_phone": "+91 9811082743",
                "contact_location": "Delhi",
                "contact_favourite": false,
                "contact_email": "3adental@sify.com",
                "contact_website": "",
                "contact_type": 4
            },
            {
                "contact_id": 368,
                "contact_name": "Avco Consultancy",
                "contact_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/v2.0/contacts/dealer.png",
                "contact_phone": "+91 9811155330",
                "contact_location": "Delhi",
                "contact_favourite": false,
                "contact_email": "avcoindia@gmail.com",
                "contact_website": "",
                "contact_type": 4
            },
            {
                "contact_id": 369,
                "contact_name": "Biotech Agencies",
                "contact_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/v2.0/contacts/dealer.png",
                "contact_phone": "+91 9811132274",
                "contact_location": "Delhi",
                "contact_favourite": false,
                "contact_email": "BIOTECHAGENCIES@GMAIL.COM",
                "contact_website": "",
                "contact_type": 4
            },
            {
                "contact_id": 370,
                "contact_name": "Lexical",
                "contact_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/v2.0/contacts/dealer.png",
                "contact_phone": "+91 9810015540",
                "contact_location": "Delhi",
                "contact_favourite": false,
                "contact_email": "lexicaldental@gmail.com",
                "contact_website": "",
                "contact_type": 4
            },
            {
                "contact_id": 371,
                "contact_name": "Oramco",
                "contact_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/v2.0/contacts/dealer.png",
                "contact_phone": "+91 9810263014",
                "contact_location": "Delhi",
                "contact_favourite": false,
                "contact_email": "oramco@yahoo.com",
                "contact_website": "",
                "contact_type": 4
            },
            {
                "contact_id": 372,
                "contact_name": "Unicorn Denmart",
                "contact_image": "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/v2.0/contacts/dealer.png",
                "contact_phone": "+91 9810986086",
                "contact_location": "Delhi",
                "contact_favourite": false,
                "contact_email": "achla@unicorndenmart.com",
                "contact_website": "",
                "contact_type": 4
            }]}]}
```

Below is My Mapped Class :

```
 import Foundation
 import RealmSwift
 import ObjectMapper

 struct  ContactRealm: Mappable {
    init?(map: Map) {
    }

    var companies:Array<companiesDetail>?

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {   
       self.companies <- map["companies"]
       self.filters <- map["filters"]
    }
}

struct companiesDetail: Mappable {
   init?(map: Map) {     
   }

   var company_id : Int?
   var company_name: String?
   var company_image : String?
   var company_website : String?
   var company_email: String?
   var company_description : String?
   var company_categories : String? 
   var company_contacts:Array<companycontacts>?

   mutating  func mapping(map: Map) { 
     self.company_id <- map["company_id"]
     self.company_name  <- map["company_name"]
     self.company_image <- map["company_image"]
     self.company_website  <- map["company_website"]
     self.company_email <- map["company_email"]
     self.company_description <- map["company_description"]
     self.company_categories  <- map["company_categories"]
     self.company_contacts <- map["company_contacts"] 
   }
}

struct companycontacts: Mappable {
   init?(map: Map) {   
   }

   var contact_id : Int?
   var contact_name : String?
   var contact_image : String?
   var contact_phone : String?
   var contact_location : String?
   var contact_favourite : String?
   var contact_email : String?
   var contact_website : String?
   var contact_type : Int?

   mutating  func mapping(map: Map) {     
      self.contact_id     <- map["contact_id"]
      self.contact_name <- map["contact_name"]
      self.contact_image   <- map["contact_image"]
      self.contact_phone     <- map["contact_phone"]
      self.contact_location <- map["contact_location"]
      self.contact_favourite   <- map["contact_favourite"]
      self.contact_email   <- map["contact_email"]
      self.contact_website   <- map["contact_website"]
      self.contact_type   <- map["contact_type"]
   }
 }
```

Comment: here `companyDetails` is an array of `companyDetail` so first you need to get the object first before accessing its value

Comment: is self.companyDetails same as var companies:Array<companiesDetail>?, in other words it is not clear from code that companyDetails same as companies

Comment: @HamzaAnsari self.companyDetails.company_name isn't it correct ? self.companyDetails is the array and company_name is the object

Comment: @HamzaAnsari How will I implement this while searching ?

Comment: you can filter like this ```self.companyDetails.filter{ $0.company_name.contains(searchKey) }```